# How to restore a delete-timer-job-history timer job without any downtime

Tags: timer-jobs

I deleted the `job-delete-timer-job-history` accidentally and even the job definition wont show up now.

what is the easiest method to re create/undelete the job without any downtime.

Nicholas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is farm scoped Timer job, so you need to run the below command in order to get deleted job back.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

But if you have the Web app target jobs then run the below one.

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication https://mywebapplication
$w.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

Comment: if thats work then please marked as answer for other benfits...:)\